# Why upvotes for questions in this meta site not added to reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I observed that up votes for questions in English Meta site are not added to the poster's reputation.

Is there no separate reputation for meta sites other than the [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) site for the stack exchange community ?

Comment: Good question.  I think it is to remove the element of competition and stress the element of cooperation in resolving problems on ELU and other sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only one meta site has the reputation system; [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

There is no main Q&A site in that case.
That is, simply stackexchange.com is not for questions and answers, but meta.stackexchange.com is.

For site-specific metas, say, [ours](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta):

> **Votes on meta do not affect your reputation**; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on English Language & Usage Stack Exchange (synchronized hourly), **though you earn separate badges**. You must have 5 reputation to participate on meta.

Comment: Worth noting is that for [tag:feature-request] tags, votes indicate an agreement or disagreement with the suggestion.

Comment: @marcellothearcane yeah, and similarly for most other tags.

Comment: yes, that's probably left over from copying from the main meta, where even upvotes there don't count for [tag:feature-request].

Comment: @marcellothearcane You are mistaken. Regardless of the tags used, voting affects reputation on Meta Stack Exchange. That means, if your feature request is disliked by many, you will collect downvotes, and therefore lose reputation.

Comment: Actually, the main site for meta.stackexchange.com is stackexchange.com, as the StackExchange menu shows. (The first two lines show the main site, and its meta site.) I would just say _Meta Stack Exchange_ is the only meta site with its own reputation.